# Why does eclipse suddenly start running slow after I run an android app on the emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse

Anyone with similar problems please relate your experiences with this issue.Thanx

Comment: Because the emulator is using a significant amount of your machines resources - ram and cpu. If you want a faster development environment, I suggest using a real device for development and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run faster you need atleast 4GB of RAM for your system. If you are using 1GB RAM then follow this

Goto AVD Manager -> Select Emulator and Choose Edit Options Give SdCard size 125 and restart your emulator.